# Can I use an ATM to convert a cheque to money into my Revolut account?

Tags: bank-account, check, atm

I think the question in the title is clear enough.

From [here](https://www.revolut.com/it-IT/help/adding-money/with-cash-or-cheque/with-cash-or-cheque) I understand it's not possible:

> Unfortunately we don't accept cash deposits or cheques to your Revolut account

but I also read at the line below:

> we will return the money to the cash depositor with a processing fee deducted

So how does this work?

Comment: What is the context of the second quote? And how do you plan to use an ATM to get money into your Revolut account? The first quote says they don't accept cash or cheque deposits. What am I missing?

Comment: If you click on the link you'll see the two quotes are just a few words apart.

Comment: The link takes me to a "404 -- The page you’re looking for could not be found" page. (Maybe they won't serve up the Italian version of the page to me.) But I found a different page with what appears to be the same wording. https://www.revolut.com/help/adding-money/with-cash-or-cheque/with-cash-or-cheque I read that as "we don't accept cash or cheques, but if you send us cash anyway, we'll send (most of) it back". So how are you thinking you will use an ATM to get around their policy?